# один и тот же php файл отображается по разному

Tags: php, html

если переходить на фаил/страницу php используя фаил

```
<?php
$file = filter_var(trim($_POST['user']));
include "C:/OpenServer/domains/msg/users/$file.php"
?>
```

где проставляется переменная вместо имени файла то все работает нормально, а если напрямую

```
header ('Location: http://msg/users/test.php');
```

переходит на тотже например вставленная

```
<img src="images\ezgif.com-crop.gif" align="top"/>
```

картинка уже не отображается
можете помочь разобраться?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема пути - файл test.php расположен в папке users, поэтому, когда подгружаете картинку, то файл картинки ищется не из корневого каталога, а из папки users.
А через include вы догружаете ваш файл, при этом место самого файла может отличаться от места файла test.php
Необходимо поправить путь к картинке примерно так:

```html
<img src="/images/ezgif.com-crop.gif" align="top"/>
```

https://www.uamedwed.com/blog/web/absolyutnyj-i-otnositelnyj-put-k-fajlam.html - материал поможет вам разобраться

Comment: Большое спасибо!